# Bootstrap gutter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to change  in my project the gutter between portfolio items.  I know, that  the easiest way is to  change padding  settings in boostrap.css for row. But  if I do  this,  I'll  change settings for  whole project.  I tried  to add new class with new padding setting, but  doesn't work. Also i  tried  this:

```
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:first-child {
  padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px; }
```

also i tried  with  padding  for `#portfolio .portfolio-item`  nothing happened.

project: http://jarmor.webd.pl/designs/kovta/template/

Comment: Adding a class should work if you are including your .css file after the bootstrap.css file.

Comment: You are already using a class (`no-gutter`) on those specific rows and your CSS is correct. From what I see now, only the portfolio section will change because that's the only place where you applied the class `no-gutter` to your `div.row`s. You can also use `#portfolio .row` or `#portfolio .no-gutter` as selectors for the rows in that section.